# BibLaTeX citation for same author and different years with page number

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to cite two references by the same author, published on different years and would like to have them together (in the same parenthesis) with page numbers, is it possible?

I have tried `\textcites[80]{smith_1930}[371]{smith_1936}` but I get this:

Smith (1930: 80) and Smith (1936: 371)

And I would like to get this:

Smith (1930: 80, 1936: 371)

This is what I am using for the references:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,sortlocale=nb_NO,sortcites,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{: }%
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%
```

Comment: There may be an option in `biblatex` to change the behaviour for multiple postnotes. However, if you only need that once `citeauthor{smith_1930} (\citeyear[80]{smith_1930}, \citeyear[371]{smith_1936})` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-apa` as selected with `style=apa,` implements APA style as closely as possible with `biblatex`. The output you describe does not conform with APA style as far as I can tell. You also set a number of options that are not strictly speaking compatible with `biblatex-apa`.

Given all that I strongly advice you either accept the APA style output from `biblatex-apa` if you need APA style or switch to a different generic non-APA author-year style if you don't need APA style.

With `authoryear-comp` the desired behaviour can easily be implemented

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcites[45]{knuth:ct:a}[80]{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Knuth (1984: 45, 1986: 80)]

---

If you must use `biblatex-apa` with the desired changes, you may want to try

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}
    {}}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}
    {\setunit{}%
     \printtext{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}}
    {\setunit{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}%
       \textcitedelim}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcites[45]{knuth:ct:a}[80]{knuth:ct:b}

ipsum \textcites[45]{knuth:ct:a}[380]{sigfridsson}

dolor \textcite[381]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I haven't tested this extensively to make sure that it covers all edge cases though, so check the output carefully.

Comment: You are great in all type of `biblatex` issues....Salute sir...